# What does "meet one's future" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

What does "meet one's future" mean in the following sentence?

> She would meet her future there when it came.

Does it mean 'meet one's end' or to die? or some other meaning?

The sentence is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=%22She+would+meet+her+future+there+when+it+came%22&source=bl&ots=wHotLYRCpY&sig=DVje7UWGCKLkL4ZtYlXKIHgzTuM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi67p-t07nJAhWFFJQKHRrPCTAQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22She%20would%20meet%20her%20future%20there%20when%20it%20came%22&f=false).

Comment: I don't think *meet her future* is exactly an idiom, but *meet one's end* is. (FWIW, I think you're right. The book's title also seems to suggest that.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not an idiom or stock phrase, so you have to read it in context.

The writer is talking about his mother going to a nursing home versus ... not entirely clear to me, but I guess remaining in the house she has been living in. And then he says that in her house, "she would meet her future there when it came". She would meet her future there, in the house, rather than in the nursing home. So "her future" here appears to be literal: whatever might happen to her at some time in the future.

So, when the future comes, she will meet that future there in her house. She will deal with whatever happens when the time comes.